# Get height of JDialog title bar?

Tags: java, swing, jdialog

How can I get the height of `JDialog` title bar?

I've tried with `getInsets().top`, but it returns `0`.

Comment: Did you do this on a visible or packed dialog?

Comment: and by using `UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());`

Comment: @camickr, yes It is visible. With packed also there is no difference.

Comment: Works fine for me. Post your SSCCE that demonstrates the problem. My SSCCE was 3 lines of code. One to create the dialog, one to make it visible and a third to print the insets.

Comment: @camickr, guess It is something buried in my code then.

Comment: Did you display the size of the dialog at the time you tried to get the insets? I'm guessing the size is also 0, which would indicate you probably have two dialogs, one that is visible and one that isn't.

Comment: *"How can I get the height of JDialog title bar?"* Why do you (think you) need to know?

Answer (score 1):

Give this a try:

```
Container c = this.getContentPane();
Point pt = c.getLocation();
pt = SwingUtilities.convertPoint(c, pt, this);
```

The `pt` variable now holds the location of the content pane, relative to the origin of the JDialog. Therefore, `pt.x` is the distance from the left edge and `pt.y` is the distance from the top.

Caveats:

- This assumes no JMenuBar. If you have one, use the location of the JMenuBar instead.
- This will include any borders added to the contentPane, or the layerdPane. You'll need to subtract those out.

Comment: This would work if the poster is using a "decorated" dialog or a LAF that paints the title bar itself. Otherwise it should be avoided.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if, if you're using  OS's own window manager, this may not be possible. The reason is that, the title bar is drawn outside Java. If you really need this information you will probably need to use JNI.

However, if you are using internal frames, you can do the following

```
JInternalFrame mydialog = new JInternalFrame();
((BasicInternalFrameUI)mydialog.getUI()).getNorthPane().getHeight();
```

But a more important question is, why do you want to know? The idea of a windowing system is so that the programmer can abstract the content of his application from the window environment. This is so that window appearances can be customised dynamically by the user, look homogeneous across all apps, and not interfere with the application's normal running.

Such an interface between OS and app would require a whole message-passing API to inform when window decorations change etc.

Comment: You may want to know it if someone (i.e., your boss) requires you to have the opened internal frames properly aligned.

Answer (score 0):

kofucii, you are on the right path - use the `dialog getInsets().top` as you did in your example.
I guess you got 0 probably because the JDialog object was invisible. Otherwise the 'top' value should be ~36 ...

Here is an isolated case:

```
package dejan.various;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JDialog;

/**
 *
 * @author dejan
 */
public class TestDialog extends JDialog implements ActionListener {
    private javax.swing.JButton testButton;

    public TestDialog() {
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(640,480));
        getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        testButton = new JButton("Click me");
        testButton.addActionListener(this);
        getContentPane().add(testButton, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        pack();
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        Insets insets = this.getInsets();
        System.out.println(insets.top);
        System.out.println(insets.left);
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
                new TestDialog().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

} // TestDialog class
```

On the STDOUT I get:

```
36
9
```

Answer (score 0):

To get insets you need to make sure your JDialog is visible. if you try to get it before showing on screen you got 0.