# How can I get the height of the title bar of a JInternalFrame?

Tags: java, swing, jinternalframe

How can I find out the height of the title bar of a `JInternalFrame`?
It would be preferable to do this in an OS and L&F independent manner.

I have seen this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7969254/get-height-of-jdialog-title-bar), which seems to be asking a similar question but for `JDialog`. However, the answers seem to suggest using the `Container` method `getInsets()`, for which the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html#getInsets%28%29) states:

> Determines the insets of this container, which indicate the size of the container's border.
>
> A Frame object, for example, has a top inset that corresponds to the height of the frame's title bar.

Unfortunately, `JInternalFrame` is not a `Frame`, but a `JComponent`. As such, this only provides the size of the border.

In the previous SO question, it was asked what the use case is... so let me explain mine. I want to create `JInternalFrame`s, popped up at the point of the mouse click, and sized to some maximum/minimum criteria, including that it is no larger than currently visible space to the bottom-right of the mouse click within the parent frame.

Consider the following SSCCE:

```
/**
 * @author amaidment
 */
public class JInternalFrameToy {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    // create top-level frame
    final JFrame frame = new JFrame("JInternalFrame Toy");
    frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 500));
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    // create desktop pane
    final JDesktopPane pane = new JDesktopPane();

    // put button on the base of the desktop pane
    JButton button = new JButton("Create Internal Frame");
    button.setSize(new Dimension(100,100));
    button.setVisible(true);
    button.setLocation(0, 0);
    button.setSelected(true);
    pane.add(button);
    frame.setContentPane(pane);

    button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
      @Override
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // create internal frame
        JInternalFrame internal = new JInternalFrame("Internal Frame", 
          true, true, false, false);
        JLabel label = new JLabel("Hello world!");

        // set size of internal frame
        Dimension parentSize = pane.getParent().getSize();
        Insets insets = internal.getInsets();
        Point point = pane.getMousePosition();
        int width = parentSize.width - (insets.left+insets.right) - point.x;
        int height = parentSize.height - (insets.top+insets.bottom) -  point.y;
        label.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width, height));

        internal.setContentPane(label);
        internal.setLocation(point);
        internal.pack();
        internal.setVisible(true);
        pane.add(internal);
        internal.toFront();
      }
    });

    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
  }
}
```

As you will see if you run this, the internal popups are sized to fit the width, but not the height - i.e. the height exceeds the frame size by... the height of the `JInternalFrame`'s title bar. As such, I want to find out this height, so that I can set the size of the `JInternalFrame` appropriately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best I have come up with so far...

```
Dimension parentSize = pane.getParent().getSize();
// get the initial preferred size - this has to be done before setContentPane()
// the height should, I think, be the border + height of the title bar
// the width is based on the title name, icon, etc. so is not useful
Dimension initSize = internal.getPreferredSize(); 

// then get the insets, which can be used for the horizontal border
Insets insets = internal.getInsets();

Point point = pane.getMousePosition();
int width = parentSize.width - (insets.left+insets.right) - point.x;
int height = parentSize.height - initSize.height -  point.y;
label.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width, height));
```

Not sure if this is the best way of doing this, so would still welcome alternative answers or suggested improvements...

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like

```
( (javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicInternalFrameUI) getUI()).getNorthPane().getPreferredSize();
```

Comment: Is that going to be OS & L&F independent?

Comment: ...mostly...I'm not sure about Nimbus, but all the current L&F's use `BasicInternalFrameUI` as there base.  You'd have to have a play around with it

Comment: Looking at the code in BasicInternalFrameUI all the layout code is here and it's the only place to access the north pane that contains the title pane.  Nimbus is based on Synth and Synth subclasses Basic so you should be ok.

Answer (score -1):

can you call getHeight() of that particular JComponent? [see documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#getHeight%28%29)